# Is there a way to play videos on full screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create an streaming app and I can't find an useful package to use for this case everything works just as an embedded view. I wish there was a package or anything customizable for this case if anybody can help this would be awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was already a similar question about that with a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431324/7834341).

> As far as I understand, the VideoPlayer doesn't know anything about where it is, but rather just expands to fit within the given space the best it can.
> I believe what you want to do is use a RotatedBox as a parent of the video and set the rotation value. [...]

Comment: BTW: Implementing this could be a good topic for a new package

Comment: I am a newbie on flutter coming from native development. Thanks for this, I will try it immediately.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked, thanks :)