# How to directly open video in landsacape when clicking the video link?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using Chewie video controller for Video Player in my flutter mobile application. I need to open video as landscape directly when I click it into video link.

Comment: maybe try changing the screen orientation: https://dev.to/mightytechno/how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-flutter-32c1

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works! But when coming back whole app will be landscape.

Comment: @Jagan try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961757/6285279 I have answered this with code.

Answer (score 1):

@override

void initState(){

```
 super.initState();

   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([

   DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,

   DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
```

]);
}

Comment: But when coming back to previous screen it remains as landscape itself. How to clear that?

Comment: use dispose method